# How do I save a file in f4 format using numpy in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have generated a coupling file and save it like this,

np.save('J', Jindep,)

This saves in J.npy format. How do I convert it in 'f4'format?

Comment: What's a `f4` format?

Comment: Are you mistaking file format for data type here?  `f4` will commonly be displayed for files containing float32s.

Comment: I'm not sure. I keep getting this error "Exception: Couplings must be in 'f4' format" when I'm trying to use the Coupling file (J.npy) which I generated. I'm not sure what to do?

Comment: What language or package is giving this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use open function to create files.

```
numpy_array = []
f = open('j.f4','w')
f.write(numpy_array)
f.close()
```